# SSRS Complex Dataset Filtering

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have couple of complex conditions in my stored procedure, e.g.

```
if @Acr != '' and @Acr != '<Select All>'
begin
delete from #temp where O_client != @Acr and O_originreason != 'RTE'
end

if @Acr = '<Select All>' 
begin
delete from #temp where LEFT(O_client, 5) = 'WS80_'
                    AND O_client IS NULL
                    AND O_originreason != 'RTE'
end

if @Chnl != '' and @Chnl != '<Select All>'
begin
delete from #temp where C_Channel != @Chnl
end
```

and I want to get rid of it, and reimplement it in DataSet filter in reports. But I can't understand how to build such complex conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I did it.

I've made an expression that returns bool and compare it with true